# SQL: How to count various group combinations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Scenario - I have a list of orders and each order can have 1 part or multiple parts to that order. I want to be able to return the part combinations and the sum of the number of times each part combination has been ordered. Ex Item A, B, C, D has been ordered 2 times. A, B, C ordered 1 time...ect.

My initial thought is to aggregate the items per order then group(count) that data.

[image]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Specify the expected result set. (Formatted text please.)

Comment: Using PostgresSQL and Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: you could have lots of combinations  as `A,C` or `A,C,D` or `B,C` ... etc. So what's the exact logic?

Comment: If an order has item A, B, C, and another order has item C, B, A, those get grouped and the counted result is 2 because the items are the same even though it is not a matching sequence.

Comment: So there's only a match if the orders contain the same number and type of parts? So `'A,A,B,C' != 'A,B,C'`, correct?

Comment: Each Item would be unique in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if you are using  mySQL. Else, change the `group_concat` with the appropriate function in your dbms. `STRING_AGG (item, ',')` for t-sql in sql server and `string_agg(item, ',')` for postgresSQL 9+

```
select items, count(*)
from
(select order, GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item ASC) as items
from table
group by order) as orders
group by items
```

THe subquery puts all the items per each order in a row.

```
select order, GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item ASC) as items
from table
group by order
```

The other query counts what you want.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for!

Comment: Apologies, I am using Microsoft SQL Server and PostgresSQL

Comment: Perfect. One last question. Would I just an Order By clause to the subquery to ensure the parts are ordered the same for any potential matching result. Example, one order has item A, B, C and one order has C, B, A. Both orders have the same items, but if not concatenated the same, they would look like distinct values.

Comment: I tried both and both work the same way, but I am getting an odd result. Example is items A, B are counted in one row, but then B, A are counted in another row. But technically A,B are in the same field and should be counted as one result. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try with order by?

Answer (score 0):

Since `STRING_AGG()` is only available in SQL Server 2017, here's a version of Kristjan Kica's answer that uses `STUFF()` and `FOR XML` instead.

```
SELECT
    items
    ,COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        yt.[order]
        ,items = STUFF((
                           SELECT ',' + t1.item 
                           FROM YourTable t1 
                           WHERE t1.[order] = yt.[order] 
                           FOR XML PATH('')
                       ) , 1, 1, '')
    FROM YourTable yt
    GROUP BY [order]
) orders
GROUP BY items
```